# PDO not updating MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Banging my head, please help.  I want to update 7 out of 14 fields in my table.  Not getting any errors, but not sending data to table either.  I'm new at PDO and have been working on this for the last 2 days.  The fields I want to update are using the bindparm with POST, the others field values are not to change.  Thank You for any help.

```
<html>
<form role="form" method="POST" action="update.php">
<div>
<label class="control-label">Contractor ID</label>
<input type="text" name="contractor_id"  />
</div>
<div>
<label class="control-label">Firstname</label>
<input type="text" name="firstname"  />
</div>
<div>
<label class="control-label">Lastname</label>
<input type="text" value="Lastname" name="lastname"  />
</div>
<div>
<label class="control-label">Address</label>
<input type="text" value="Address" name="address"  />
</div>
<div>
<label class="control-label">City</label>
<input type="text" value="City" name="city" />
</div>
<div>
<label class="control-label">State</label>
<input type="text" value="State" name="state" />
</div>
<div>
<label class="control-label">Zipcode</label>
<input type="text" value="Zipcode" name="zip" />
</div>
<div>
<label class="control-label">Email</label>
<input type="text" value="Email" name="email"  />
</div>
<div class="margiv-top-10">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="email" value="Update" >
</div>
</form>
</html>
```

PHP

```
try {
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$pdo ->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo 'Connected to database';
echo '<br>';

$sql = "UPDATE contractor_keys SET  
    contractor_id = :contractor_id,
    firstname = :firstname,
    lastname = :lastname,
    address = :address,
    city = :city,
    state = :state, 
    zip = :zip,
    email = :email,
    areacode = :areacode,
    phonenumber = :phonenumber,
    ssnumber = :ssnumber,
    rate = :rate,
    mykey = :mykey,
    passwd = :passwd

WHERE contractor_id = :contractor_id";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);  

$stmt->bindParam(':contractor_id', $contractor_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);                               
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $_POST['firstname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $_POST['lastname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);    
$stmt->bindParam(':address', $_POST['address'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':city', $_POST['city'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':state', $_POST['state'], PDO::PARAM_STR);   
$stmt->bindParam(':zip', $_POST['zip'], PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':areacode', $arecode, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt->bindParam(':phonenumber', $phonenumber, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':ssnumber', $ssnumber, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':rate', $rate, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt->bindParam(':mykey', $mykey, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':passwd', $passwd, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->execute(); 
echo 'Record Updated';

}

catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: At some point you might want to evaluate various ORMs like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) or [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) because this code can quickly become an unmaintainable nightmare. What you've got here is getting pretty complicated.

Comment: Where do you set `$contractor_id`? Maybe that should be `$_POST['contractor_id']`?

Comment: Why are you updating `contractor_id` to the same value as in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: contractor_id is what I'm searching for to be valid to make changes to the record, I wasn't sure if I need to include in the $sql UPDATE, ive tried it without as well.  I just want the user to type in there contractor_id then update the record with the values entered into the HTML form

Comment: tadman, I only have 14 fields in my database and there will be no more.  is this acceptable, or I guess I don't know what you mean by to complicated

Comment: Barner, I set contractor_id in the html form, then post it to update.php file

Comment: Complicated means a lot of redundant code that's taking a ton of space for no reason (space = lines of code), is unreadable, is hard to maintain because you access variables from superglobal array and god knows where else from, has no structure so it's not easy to determine what the author wanted etc. Usually, complex code gets a nice `ctrl + a` followed by `delete`, then it gets rewritten in a few lines of testable code. That's what complex is - something you should take behind the barn and shoot it dead. Then rewrite it in a shorter, concise, readable way.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism I know I've got a lot to learn.  I will check out Doctrine and Propel per your suggestion.  You probable mean I could use two or three lines of code for my html input, and even my PDO code, then just loop my 14 variables thru that code right?  What are the chances of you giving me a sample.  I've seen something of the sort, but didn't understand it.  Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `$contractor_id` by `$_POST["contractor_id"]`.See the code below:

**Before**:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':contractor_id', $contractor_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

**After**:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':contractor_id', $_POST["contractor_id"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

One more thing.You dont need to update the contractor_id field if you are using it in the where condition. See the code below:

**Before:**

```
$sql = "UPDATE contractor_keys SET  
    contractor_id = :contractor_id,
    firstname = :firstname,
    lastname = :lastname,
    address = :address,
    city = :city,
    state = :state, 
    zip = :zip,
    email = :email,
    areacode = :areacode,
    phonenumber = :phonenumber,
    ssnumber = :ssnumber,
    rate = :rate,
    mykey = :mykey,
    passwd = :passwd

WHERE contractor_id = :contractor_id";
```

**After:**

```
$sql = "UPDATE contractor_keys SET  
    firstname = :firstname,
    lastname = :lastname,
    address = :address,
    city = :city,
    state = :state, 
    zip = :zip,
    email = :email,
    areacode = :areacode,
    phonenumber = :phonenumber,
    ssnumber = :ssnumber,
    rate = :rate,
    mykey = :mykey,
    passwd = :passwd

WHERE contractor_id = :contractor_id";
```

Comment: Thank you mssantos,  that worked.  I was so close, but it's those little things that get you.  Have a good one!

Comment: I'm glad to help you. If my answer helped you , could you vote?

Comment: If my answer helped you , could you accept it, not vote up?

Comment: I'm new at this sorry, where do I accept it? Ive looked all over the place, but must be blind!

Comment: Click the tick (check mark) on left under the vote arrows.